# multidex error on android studio 3

Tags: android, android-multidex

Before upgrading to AS 3, I used multidex in my project just fine, after upgrading It started getting this error each time i try to run the app on a device or even generate an APK

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzp;
>   Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzp; Error:  at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
>   Error:    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
>   Error:    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>   Error:    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>   Error:    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>   Error:    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

Please not that all i did was update AS and gradle plguin to 3.0.0. I tried going back to 2.3.3, but It tells me the project is incompatible.

Here is my Multidex code:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.mohammed.billmob"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
```

and my application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);


    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

and these are the app dependencies:

```
dependencies {



    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })



    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'

   // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.6.0'

    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.0'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
/*    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2'*/


    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Does it work after you run `./gradlew clean` ?

Comment: no, it doesn't. I even tried deleting the .gradle folder from the project directory, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sol i solved it by downgrading firebase and google dependencies to 11.4.2 to match the firebase ui version provided here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:
1. Enable multiDex:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

More info:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

2. Configure gradle plugin and gradle version:

> ```
> //gradle-wrapper.properties
> distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
> //project build.gradle
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
> ```

More info:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html